# how to specify in R formula with some independent variables having spaces

Tags: r

I am using `ucm` in R. There is a formula argument to it. I have a response variable `y` and two predictors named `"abc def" and jkl`. I want the formula to look like `y ~ abc def + jkl`. But the space between abc and def is a problem. How do I specify the formula so that R understands that abc def is just one name? Right now, I am getting the error `"Error in terms.formula(formula) : '.' in formula and no 'data' argument"` when I specify the formula as below.

```
ucm_Forecast=function(x,h,xreg){
  if (ncol(xreg)>=1){   
    xregFit=data.frame(xreg[1:length(x),])
    x<-x/10000
    d<-cbind(data.frame(x=x),xregFit)
    fit_ucm=ucm(**x~.**,data=d, level = TRUE, slope=TRUE, cycle = TRUE, cycle.period = 365.25/52)        

    print("right before predict")  
    indep <- paste(names(d)[2:ncol(d)], collapse= "+")
    newdata1 <- SSModel(as.formula(paste0("rep(NA,h) ~ ", indep, 
                                          "+ SSMtrend(2, Q =  list(fit_ucm$est.var.level,fit_ucm$est.var.slope))",
                                          "+ SSMcycle(365.25/52, Q = fit_ucm$est.var.cycle)")), 
                        H = fit_ucm$irr.var, data=as.data.frame(xreg[(length(x)+1):(length(x)+h),]))
    fcst<-predict(fit_ucm$model, newdata=newdata1)

    #fcst<-predict(fitucm$model, xreg=xreg[(length(x)+1):(length(x)+h),])
    print("right after predict")
    fcst<-fcst*10000
    print(fcst)
  } else {
    x=ts(filter(Model_Dataset,Category==Cat,Date<FcstDate)$`Gross Sales`)
    x<-x*10000
    x<-x/10000
    x<-ts(x)
    x
    fitucm<- ucm(formula = x~0, data = x, level = TRUE, slope=TRUE)
    fcst<-predict(fitucm$model, n.ahead = h)
    fcst<-fcst*10000
    fcst
  }
  return(fcst)
}
```

Edited code according to r2evans answer is below. Now I get the error

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  object 'abc.def' not found
Called from: eval(predvars, data, env)
```

Edited code

```
 ucm_Forecast=function(x,h,xreg){

      print("h=")
      print(h)
      if (ncol(xreg)>=1){


         xregFit=data.frame(xreg[1:length(x),])
        # xregFcst=data.frame(xreg[(length(x)+1):nrow(xreg),])
        # 
        # colnames(xregFit)=colnames(xreg)
        # colnames(xregFcst)=colnames(xreg)
        x<-x/10000
        d<-cbind(data.frame(x=x),xregFit)
        #fit_ucm=ucm(x~.,data=d, level = TRUE, slope=TRUE, cycle = TRUE, cycle.period = 365.25/52)



        independent <- paste0("`", names(d)[-1], "`", collapse = " + ")

        #d<-cbind(as.data.frame(x),xreg[1:length(x),])

      fit_ucm<- ucm(as.formula(paste("`",names(d[1]),"` ~", independent)), data = d, level = TRUE, slope=TRUE, cycle = TRUE, cycle.period = 365.25/52)
        #fit_ucm<- ucm(formula=x~Shipping_Days+Orders_Min_2_Weeks+Orders_Pre_1_Weeks, data = d, level = TRUE, slope=TRUE, cycle = TRUE, cycle.period = 365.25/52)
      #  fit_ucm<- ucm(as.formula(paste0(names(d[1]),"~.")), data = d, level = TRUE, slope=TRUE, cycle = TRUE, cycle.period = 365.25/52)
         print("right before predict")


        indep <- paste(names(d)[2:ncol(d)], collapse= "+")
        newdata1 <- SSModel(as.formula(paste0("rep(NA,h) ~ ", indep, 
                                              "+ SSMtrend(2, Q =  list(fit_ucm$est.var.level,fit_ucm$est.var.slope))",
                                              "+ SSMcycle(365.25/52, Q = fit_ucm$est.var.cycle)")), H = fit_ucm$irr.var, data=as.data.frame(xreg[(length(x)+1):(length(x)+h),]))
        fcst<-predict(fit_ucm$model, newdata=newdata1)

        #fcst<-predict(fitucm$model, xreg=xreg[(length(x)+1):(length(x)+h),])
        print("right after predict")
        fcst<-fcst*10000
        print(fcst)

      } else {

        x=ts(filter(Model_Dataset,Category==Cat,Date<FcstDate)$`Gross Sales`)
        x<-x*10000
        x<-x/10000
        x<-ts(x)

        x
        fitucm<- ucm(formula = x~0, data = x, level = TRUE, slope=TRUE)
        fcst<-predict(fitucm$model, n.ahead = h)
        fcst<-fcst*10000
        fcst
      }

      return(fcst)
    }
```

I put check.names=FALSE but I still get another error.

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , as.character(dep.var)) : 
  undefined columns selected
Called from: `[.data.frame`(data, , as.character(dep.var))
```

Here is the code.

```
ucm_Forecast=function(x,h,xreg){

  print("h=")
  print(h)
  if (ncol(xreg)>=1){


     xregFit=data.frame(xreg[1:length(x),],check.names=FALSE)
    print( colnames(xregFit))

    x<-x/10000
    d<-cbind(data.frame(x=x),xregFit)


    independent <- paste0("`", names(d)[-1], "`", collapse = " + ")
    print("dfgh")

**The statement below errors out**  
  fit_ucm<- ucm(as.formula(paste("`",names(d[1]),"` ~", independent)), data = d, level = TRUE, slope=TRUE, cycle = TRUE, cycle.period = 365.25/52)

     print("right before predict")


    indep <- paste(names(d)[2:ncol(d)], collapse= "+")
    newdata1 <- SSModel(as.formula(paste0("rep(NA,h) ~ ", indep, 
                                          "+ SSMtrend(2, Q =  list(fit_ucm$est.var.level,fit_ucm$est.var.slope))",
                                          "+ SSMcycle(365.25/52, Q = fit_ucm$est.var.cycle)")), H = fit_ucm$irr.var, data=as.data.frame(xreg[(length(x)+1):(length(x)+h),]))
    fcst<-predict(fit_ucm$model, newdata=newdata1)

    #fcst<-predict(fitucm$model, xreg=xreg[(length(x)+1):(length(x)+h),])
    print("right after predict")
    fcst<-fcst*10000
    print(fcst)

  } else {

    x=ts(filter(Model_Dataset,Category==Cat,Date<FcstDate)$`Gross Sales`)
    x<-x*10000
    x<-x/10000
    x<-ts(x)


    fitucm<- ucm(formula = x~0, data = x, level = TRUE, slope=TRUE)
    fcst<-predict(fitucm$model, n.ahead = h)
    fcst<-fcst*10000
    fcst
  }

  return(fcst)
}
```

Comment: problem variables like that can typically be referenced using backticks, as in `\`abc def\``

Comment: I want to create the formula dynamically. I don't want any hard-coding.

Comment: It's a function bug, see my comment to @r2evans's answer. I suggest you contact `maintainer('rucm')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmatically:

```r
names(mtcars)[2] <- "cyl cyl"
sprintf(ifelse(grepl(" ", names(mtcars)), "`%s`", "%s"), names(mtcars))
#  [1] "mpg"       "`cyl cyl`" "disp"      "hp"        "drat"      "wt"        "qsec"     
#  [8] "vs"        "am"        "gear"      "carb"
```

I think you can use that directly in your code, perhaps with (untested):

```r
    indep <- names(d)[-1]
    indep <- sprintf(ifelse(grepl(" ", indep), "`%s`", "%s"), indep)
    indep <- paste(indep, collapse = "+")
```

(Broken out for readability, I'm confident you can compactify this code.)

Or you can just always backtick everything, as it still works even if it is not necessary.

```r
    indep <- paste0("`", names(d)[-1], "`", collapse = "+")
```

---

Demonstration, using `mtcars` and `lm`:

```r
names(mtcars)[2] <- "cyl cyl"
indep <- sprintf(ifelse(grepl(" ", names(mtcars)[-1]), "`%s`", "%s"), names(mtcars)[-1])
indep <- paste(indep, collapse = " + ")
indep
# [1] "`cyl cyl` + disp + hp + drat + wt + qsec + vs + am + gear + carb"
lm(as.formula(paste("mpg ~", indep)), data = mtcars)
# Call:
# lm(formula = as.formula(paste("mpg ~", indep)), data = mtcars)
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)    `cyl cyl`         disp           hp         drat           wt         qsec  
#    12.30337     -0.11144      0.01334     -0.02148      0.78711     -3.71530      0.82104  
#          vs           am         gear         carb  
#     0.31776      2.52023      0.65541     -0.19942
```

and

```r
indep <- paste0("`", names(mtcars)[-1], "`", collapse = " + ")
indep
# [1] "`cyl cyl` + `disp` + `hp` + `drat` + `wt` + `qsec` + `vs` + `am` + `gear` + `carb`"
lm(as.formula(paste("mpg ~", indep)), data = mtcars)
# Call:
# lm(formula = as.formula(paste("mpg ~", indep)), data = mtcars)
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)    `cyl cyl`         disp           hp         drat           wt         qsec  
#    12.30337     -0.11144      0.01334     -0.02148      0.78711     -3.71530      0.82104  
#          vs           am         gear         carb  
#     0.31776      2.52023      0.65541     -0.19942
```

---

**Edit**: the next error you're seeing (`object 'abc.def' not found`) is likely due to you re-framing things. Using the modified `mtcars` from before,

```r
data.frame(mtcars[1:3,])
#                mpg cyl.cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4     21.0       6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0       6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710    22.8       4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1

data.frame(mtcars[1:3,], check.names = FALSE)
#                mpg cyl cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4     21.0       6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0       6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710    22.8       4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Notice that the first example replaced the `"cyl cyl"` name with `"cyl.cyl"`. This behavior can be suppressed with `check.names = FALSE` as shown in the second example.

Comment: But in this case it's a function bug. The source has a code line `all_terms <- terms(formula)` and to call `terms(y~.)` throws the error in the question.

Comment: @Rui Barradas I am surprised they couldn't see that one could use ".". Thank you.

Comment: @r2evans What is cc()? Thank you.

Comment: @user2371765, oops, `cc` is my clear-copy function I use for reprexing things (dates to well before the `reprex` package).

Comment: @r2evans What is reprexing? Please see my edited question. Thank you.

Comment: `repr`oducible `ex`ample. Normally it's just *"please provide a reprex"*, which migrated into the [`reprex`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reprex/index.html) package, specifically intended to *"render small snippets of code to target formats that include both code and output"*. In the case of my `cc` function, it just copies the R console directly and convert `> myfun(a,b,c)` and `[1] 123` into `myfun(a,b,c)` and `# [1] 123` for easy SO formatting (with a couple of other bells and whistles, nothing fancy).

Comment: See my edit, try `check.names=FALSE` whenever you re-`data.frame` data.

Comment: I'm not at all surprised: you added `check.names=` in **one** of your calls, not both. So the names in the second frame are different.

Comment: I printed the names in d; d is a result of the cbind. These names do not have the ".". What second frame are you referring to?

Comment: Edit your function and add `browser()` on the line immediately before `ucm`. Source the function/file. Run your function with your data (whatever that looks like). Before you run `ucm`, look at the results from `paste("\`",names(d[1]),"\` ~", independent)`, and you will see that your dependent variable `"x"` is actually listed as `" x "` (a space both before and after), because you chose to use `paste` instead of `paste0`. Then try `paste0` and see if that works. (Behold the power of `browser()` and `debug(ucm_Forecast)`.)

Comment: Thank you. I needed paste0 instead of paste. I wish R adhered to the principle of least surprise espoused by Ruby. Why would they put "." in lieu of spaces between names?

Comment: Interesting question, perhaps dating back a couple of decades to R's (and S's) more formative years. *"Least surprise"* is relative, of course. It certainly is skipping a label of *"consistent behavior"* in some places. But I also think similar comments could be made when transitioning from one language (with proficiency) to a new language.

Comment: "Least surprise" is relative, but I believe there is some degree of common agreement regarding to what extent "vigilantism" is desirable in a language. I can't fathom why any language would want to change/mangle an identifier/name without warning. Either disallow names with spaces, or leave them alone.  I understand R is free, but I feel like I still haven't got my money's worth (to quote Amy from "The Big Bang theory").

Comment: While I understand the inconsistencies ... we will be unable to change things. R has many ... "nuances" ... that are frustrating, but I'm able to work around them sufficiently to be able to use R's other super-powers quite well. (And "extended discussions" like this in an SO answer are most certainly out of the intended use.) I'm glad I was able to help you figure out the problem!

Comment: Thank you for your help.